# Single-statement transactional consistency

Tags: sql-server, transaction, isolation-level

I ran into [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21469107) on StackOverflow the other day. To quote comments from the question author, the situation seems "somewhat horrifying". A similar situation is set up in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4772475).

My rule-of-thumb understanding has always been that a single statement in SQL executes "atomically". That is, under any default configuration, a single statement which executes to success (i.e. is not deadlocked or otherwise aborted), is free of any latent concurrency concerns.

Yet the two Q&As which I link to suggest not.

The most basic scenario to illustrate the problem seems to be this self-join:

```
SELECT
     t1.*
    ,t2.*

FROM 
    some_table AS t1

FULL OUTER JOIN 
    some_table AS t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id
```

Are there any circumstances under which `t1` does not need to be fully consistent with `t2`, and this query could therefore return NULLS on one side or the other of the full-join, because the data for t1 is acquired at a different time than the data for t2 and thus each may reference different data (even though it is the same table referenced within a single statement)?

My assumption has always been that a single statement (referencing multiple tables, or referencing certain tables multiple times) acquires all data it requires as a single consistent snapshot of the database at a certain step in time. If the isolation level is `READ COMMITTED`, then I assumed the snapshot was of all committed data at the time the individual statement began.

My understanding of the RCSI feature was that it extended this assumed snapshot guarantee to multi-statement transactions.

I'm shocked (though not entirely surprised) to find this seems not to be the case, and that my basic understanding of many years seems to be upended.

Information about this seems very thin on the ground. As the author of [this 2014 article](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/02/t-sql-queries/confusion-caused-by-trusting-acid) says, this behaviour seems "capable of misleading even experienced database practitioners".

That article shows that even a quite common style of SELECT query seems capable of having its underlying data modified mid-execution, and returning results that then violate the explicit logical criteria of the WHERE clause. It seems absurd that this style of behaviour could ever be the default.

**Questions**

Is there any information from Microsoft (or in an SQL standard) that explicitly specifies and confirms this behaviour?

And what are the settings (at a session level or statement level) necessary to gain the guarantee that a single statement works from the equivalent of a single consistent snapshot of all data?

Answer (score 7):

You've asked multiple questions - below answers some of them but I'm not going to find links from Microsoft or the SQL Standard for you.

> Are there any circumstances under which t1 does not need to be fully
> consistent with t2

Yes.

This is very easy to demonstrate

### Connection 1

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS some_table

CREATE TABLE some_table (id int);

INSERT some_table 
SELECT value
FROM generate_series(1, 100000)

DECLARE @I int = 100000
WHILE @I <= 2000000
    BEGIN
    INSERT some_table VALUES (@I);
    SET @I = @I + 1
    END
```

### Connection 2

(You can remove the `WITH (READCOMMITTEDLOCK)` if you know that you definitely don't have RCSI enabled)

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
--SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;

SELECT
     t1.*
    ,t2.*
FROM 
    some_table AS t1  WITH (READCOMMITTEDLOCK)
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    some_table AS t2   WITH (READCOMMITTEDLOCK)
    ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE t1.id IS NULL OR t2.id IS NULL
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

For me I just needed to start "Connection 1" running and hop over to another window and run the query in "Connection 2" once before getting a result.

SQL Server chose a hash join and the row counts clearly show that since reading the table for the `t1` instance and building the hash table additional rows were added to the underlying table and read by the `t2` instance.

[image]

> My understanding of the RCSI feature was that it extended this assumed
> snapshot guarantee to multi-statement transactions.

This understanding is wrong. The RCSI feature provides a snapshot guarantee for a single statement. The full blown `SNAPSHOT` isolation level extends this across multiple statements.

> And what are the settings (at a session level or statement level)
> necessary to gain the guarantee that a single statement works from the equivalent of a single consistent snapshot of all data?

Either of the snapshot isolation levels guarantee this. For the pessimistic isolation levels only `SERIALIAZBLE` guarantees this.

The above code also behaves the same at `REPEATABLE READ` - whilst this locks the rows read during the scan for `t1` and retains the locks this doesn't prevent additional rows being added and read by `t2` (the repeatable read variant *may* escalate its row/page locks to a table lock and so end up blocking the inserts but this isn't guaranteed and I didn't see this happen successfully in a few attempted runs on my instance - you may need to run "Connection 2" multiple times if you do encounter this. Please ensure "Connection 1" is still showing up as "Executing" if doing so).